# laravel auth apply bcrypt to username/email

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

The laravel auth system uses bcrypt for saving passwords. Is it possible to do the same for the username (i.e. email)? I want to avoid that any customer email addresses are save plain text in the DB.

EDIT:

I don't need to know the user email for any other functionality. I only want the users to be able to login with their email address. I am just wondering if there is an easy way to do this with the integrated laravel auth system or if I need to write the whole auth logic myself

Comment: After you apply bcrypt on email, you can't decrypt it. Can only compare the hash value to another hash value.

Comment: As long as you're ok never knowing what the emails are, then sure. It will also be impossible to search by username, since you won't be able to index the column usefully. Well, not impossible, but incredibly expensive.

Comment: I don't need to know the user email for any other functionality. I only want the users to be able to login with their email address. I am just wondering if there is an easy way to do this with the integrated laravel auth system or if I need to write the whole auth logic myself

Comment: You can implement encryption with algorithm such as RSA so that you can decrypt the value later as per requirement.

Answer (score 1):

The general flow for authenticating a user against a hashed password is:

1. User submits username and password
2. One user entity is fetched from database based on the username
3. Password is checked using `password_verify`
4. User is authenticated (or not)

This relies on the username being stored in plain-text, since otherwise the second step cannot be performed. If you were to hash the username as well, the process would need to become:

1. User submits username and password
2. **Every** user is fetched from the database
3. Username and password are both checked using `password_verify`
4. User is authenticated (or not)

This is in theory a workable approach, but it is not at all scalable. Step 2 requires either fetching all users into memory, or paging through them, both of which will add significant overhead. Verifying hashed data is also (by design) an expensive operation, and if you have to perform it twice *for every user in your database*, every time *anyone* logs in, you'll quickly run into trouble.

I think one thing you might be missing is that `password_hash` generates a different hash each time, even for the same input string. This is what makes the second approach unworkable, since it prevents looking up a single user.

Additionally, as was mentioned in the comments, anything hashed using bcrypt is going to stay hashed. You might not need to actually send emails to the user, but you'll also lose the ability to display their username on the site, either in a user profile page or alongside any content/etc.

Comment: I guess this is due to brcypt..? What about using a method with a salt that is not unique to each user. Then I could hash it before and then query the DB to find a match

Comment: In theory, sure. But the reason bcrypt is accepted as an industry standard is due to its design and security. The moment you start stripping bits of it away, the less point there is in hashing the usernames at all. If you don't need usernames for anything else (email sending/displaying in a header/etc), then they might as well just be a second password - in which case, just require longer passwords in the first place, and don't bother with usernames.

Comment: Ok, one more weird idea. What if I use bcrypt on the username/email and store the password as plain text.